# What character codes could these be?

Tags: binary-analysis, byte-code

Good day. I have these character codes in a binary file (Adobe After Effects Project) that represent a string. If  I change them the text inside the application changes. However, for the life of me, I do not understand what kind of character codes these are. They're not ASCII codes, they're not Hex codes, they're not anything I can recognize. Here's a couple of examples:

```
 [ 42 42 80 72 85 82 82 81 3 ]
```

translates to: "GGmeroon".

And

```
 [ 38 68 80 72 85 68 3 ]
```

translates to: "Camera".

(Uppercase/lowercase matters).

Can you help me find a way to translate these codes?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. So what are those numbers? Are they in hexadecimal or decimal representation? Given the pattern from the work (duplicate letters) reoccurs in the "encoded" form this is probably something very simple like xoring each character by a specific (fixed) value or so ...

Comment: in decimal : encoded char + 29 = ascii char

Answer (score 2):

As Commented by@gordon it is simply a trivial subtraction algorithm

```
:\>type ggmer.py
instrs  =   [   list("GGmeroon"),           list("Camera")      ]
outdec =    [   [42,42,80,72,85,82,82,81],  [38,68,80,72,85,68] ]

l1 = len(instrs[0])
l2 = len(instrs[1])

for i in range(0,l1,1):
    print( ord(instrs[0][i])-outdec[0][i],end = " ")

print("\n")

for i in range(0,l2,1):
    print( ord(instrs[1][i])-outdec[1][i],end = " ")
```

result

```
:\>python ggmer.py
29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29

29 29 29 29 29 29
:\>
```